# identify 5-tuple flows by hash value in Python

Tags: python, hash

I identify Internet **traffic flows** by their **5-tuple** (src IP, dst port, sport, dport, transport protocol number) and I would like turn this 5-tuple into a much more compact **alphanumeric ID** for internal use in my script.

What choices do I have in Python?

I read that the built-in function `hash` is only **consistent OS-wise**, so I would prefer something else.

I will only ever have to deal with **no more than a few hundreds** different 5-tuples.

Comment: Worse, `hash` isn't even consistent across multiple runs of the same program in some versions (hash randomization).

Comment: Simple encodings like `str(flow)` and `base64encode(flow)` are alphanumeric and unique. A hash will usually take more space than such a short tuple itself, so why do you want them?

Comment: I would like also a user to refer to a flow with an alphanumeric string, when he wants to perform some functions on it. Basically, I want my script to take as input the ID of a flow or of more flows, and it would be cumbersome to use the entire 5-tuple

Comment: You are mixing stuff up there. If you want a ID you have to assign one, ie tell the user that he can type 1 instead of ("192.168.0.1","8.8.8.8", 29380,53,0). When you hash the tuple you get something like `40eb5f19cad7d714da1ef3074a7f3216` which is much harder to write down correctly than the tuple.

Comment: but it can be copied and pasted with two clicks :)

Comment: the user is me, by the way :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just choose your own hash function:

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.md5()
t = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # whatever
t_as_string = str(t)
hash.update(t_as_string)
print hash.hexdigest()
```

You can use any of the functions in [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html). And since this isn't a security issue, it doesn't really matter which one...

**BUT:** wanna bet, comparing tuples will be faster / more efficient?

Comment: Thanks. I guess in the last line it's `hash.hexdigest()`, right? One more thing: as far as I can tell from the documentation, I have to call the constructor `hashlib.md5()` each time I want to compute a hash, otherwise it will just concatenate a new string to the previous and compute the resulting hash value. Is this correct?

Comment: @RickyRobinson, correct (regarding calling the constructor for each hash you want to compute), corrected (regarding the bug in my code), thanks

Comment: @DarenThomas I dont understand your "BUT: wanna bet, ..." statement, could you elaborate how it's related to this question?

Answer (score 2):

The following Python Hash function, by Ewen Cheslack-Postava, shall remain consistent accross several OS and CPU :
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhashxx/

Comment: Should I prefer it over `hashlib`?

Comment: If you fear that hashlib is not OS independent, and your application needs to be portable, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

are you worried about collisions across OS's? is that your issue?

But since you are only dealing with a few hundred of 5tuples cant you apply some kind of hash collusion resolution techniques like chaining or open addressing etc.

If I am not missing anything else I believe the above method is better than devising a new hashing algorithm yourself.

Comment: My only concern is that I might want to dump traffic and categorize it by flow on one machine and then analyze it on another. So if I can avoid future migraines due to such small things as hash not returning the same value across different OSs, I would :)

Comment: aah! I get what you are saying. you can give it a try but in my experience such universal solutions often exist. The above mentioned lib might work in x,y OS's but might go kaput in z OS. what then? its better to design your system to be tolerant from ground up since `hash` seems to be the core of your application. think about it...